# BufferedReader is stuck when output is empty

Tags: android, bufferedreader, urlconnection

I used BufferedReader to proccess the output of a webpage. When the output of webpage is empty (I used `Response.Clear` in web side), the last line `Log.e("status","finish")` does nothing. Is `reader.readLine()` being stucked in empty output? If yes, how should I check if **response** is empty before using a **reader**?

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + "utf-8");
connection.connect(); // The code works same without this. Do I need this?
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(query.getBytes("utf-8"));
    Log.e("status", "post Done"); // This works
}
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));

String line="";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    urlData += line;
}
reader.close();

Log.e("status","finish");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is "stucked", although the correct wording is that it is "blocked". It blocks until it receives a line of text. When the socket is closed at the other party, the TCP connection will indicate termination and the input stream gets closed. At that point you would retrieve `null` as specified by the API. However, before that happens the high level `readLine` routine will happily wait until the end of time, or until a time-out is generated by a lower layer.

As such, it might not be a good idea to use `readLine` or even stream if you don't trust your server connection to return any data. You can however set the socket to time-out and generate an exception instead using [`Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) - if you think that the server not responding is an exceptional problem.

Comment: Thank you. What are other ways rather than `readline` or `stream` to consume a connection output?

Comment: You can use a `AsynchronousSocketChannel`. But be prepared for some learning curve if you do. Just handling an exception might be better for higher level purposes.